# Usage of "that is"

Tags: conjunctions

Is the usage of *that is* correct here? And why is it correct? (main reason for the asking: I have not seen a sentence that is joined by *that is*)

> Out of the experiments, only one is successful, that is, produces same same output in both set of input.

Comment: There's no need to click on the tick, if you just like the answer click on the arrow. If you prefer someone else's answer you can always change your mind, and click on the green tick next to their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, `that is` is only a different way of saying: [i.e.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48278/that-is-vs-i-e)

> "The actual term i.e. is an abbreviation of id est in Latin, which
>   literally means "that is". In fact, when I see i.e., I cannot help but
>   say "that is" in my head."

Answer (score 1):

The words "that is" might be replaced with "in other words" or "let me explain that some more".

The usage you mentioned is correct.